# Unable to run multiple subdomains with bitnami.conf

Tags: dns, apache2, subdomain, bitnami

I'm trying to run 2 subdmains and 1 domain. Below are the urls:

`example.com`

`app1.example.com`

`app2.example.com`

I created `A` records for all of them pointing to the default IP address.

Here is my `bitnami.conf` file

```
ServerName example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app1_website
        ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app2_website
        ServerName app2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The folders `default_website`, `app1_website` and `app2_website` have their respective `index.html` files with just a `<h>` tag to identify the website.

When I access `example.com` in the browser I get the below error:

```
example.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

When I access `app1.example.com` in the browser I get the below error:

```
app1.example.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

When I access `app2.example.com` in the browser I get the below error:

```
 Forbidden
 You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I'm very new to `bitnami` and `apache2`. What is the mistake I'm doing?

Update :

Here is my updated `bitnami.conf` file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
       <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app1_website
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app1_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>
    ServerName app1.example.com
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app2_website
     <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app2_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>
    ServerName app2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm able to access `app2.example.com` but not the other 2 urls.

Comment: your domain is not configured properly

Comment: @ points to ip address, app1 points to ip address, app2 points to ip address. When i type in the ip address the default_website is loading

Comment: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` means it doesn't point to anything, so your domain is not configured properly or dns servers did not propagate yet (`NXDOMAIN` => `Non existing domain`)

Comment: Is it possible that one subdomain was propagated while the others didn't? I updated my NS servers 2 hours before making changes to `.conf` file

Comment: @FlashThunder I used `https://dnschecker.org` tool to check the propagation. It shows that the urls are pointing to the right ip address. I deleted all the A records and added them again. Now all 3 websites are showing the same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: what exact error?

Comment: server IP address could not be found. `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN `. Should I just wait for another couple of hours?

Comment: can you share the real domain name?

Comment: @DusanBajic `http://zavapp.com/`, `http://app.zavapp.com/`, `http://support.zavapp.com/`

Comment: Static, angular and support websites are ready :). If you get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` in your browser, then you have some problems with DNS resolution/caching in your local network (where your browser resides).

Comment: @DusanBajic, yup all the urls are working now. The problem was waiting for the DNS to propagate. One url being propagated confused me.

Comment: That probably was because you asked your DNS for all the others before propagation, and the third one did propagate. Operating system and DNS servers do cache requests. Doesn't matter if dnschecker.org works, as it doesn't use the same DNS servers as you do (probably).

Answer (score 0):

`serveralias` is what you are missing.

Add serveralias to each Virtualhost config. and alias should be the exact subdomain you want for each host.